# GET POST errors

Tags: php

All, I posted a code in a forum before and no one was able to answer this.
The "Sign Up" and "logout" are both buttons with value types on other pages that are linked to this page code called login.php

The problem is that I keep getting an undefined index. Is there a way to call it better?

I have..

```
if ($_POST['submit']=="Sign Up") {
```

and..

```
if($_GET["logout"]==1 AND $_SESSION['id']) { session_destroy();
        header("Location:logout.php");      
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/isset + http://php.net/var_dump

Comment: Where exactly do you get the `undefined index` - which line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both POST and GET variables *must* not be send at all, always use a scheme similar to this one:

```
$var = isset($_POST['fieldname']) ? $_POST['fieldname'] : null;
if ( !isset($var) )
{
    // errorhandling
}
else
{
    // proceed ...
```

The error you get indicates that at least one of your POST and/or GET variables is either not set or misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

As Axel points out, check if $_POST has the value for "submit" using isset() function, if it is set, the you can access the value the way you are doing. If $_POST does not have the value for that, it means that it is not being sent.

So, in your HTML, check that the button is indeed called that way and that it is inside a  tag with the ACTION attribute and METHOD set to POST.

Also be careful with comparing with 1, since in PHP is also means true.